# How to show a messagebox after updating the frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, messagebox, ttk

The mainframe contains a label whose text element corresponds to a counter variable. To increase the counter, the user can press the increment button.

After 10 increments, I want to show a messagebox asking the user if they want to continue incrementing.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

counter = 0

def increment():
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1

    count_label.config(text=str(counter))

    if counter % 10 == 0:
        # The previous count_label.config(text=str(counter)) statement should update the label before showing the messagebox, but it isn't
        messagebox.askyesno(title="Counted 10 times", message="You have counted 10 times. Continue counting?")

root = tk.Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)

count_label = ttk.Label(mainframe, text="0")
increment_btn = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="increment", command=increment)

mainframe.pack(fill="both")
count_label.pack(side="top")
increment_btn.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

However, the message box is displayed before the label's text variable is updated. The label shows 9 instead of 10 when the message box appears, and the label is updated after the message box is closed.
How do I update the label before the message box appears?

Comment: Try adding `root.update()` just after the `.configure`. Be careful as `.update()` can also handle events and `.after` scripts. As long as you are careful, there shouldn't be a problem with `.update()`

Comment: I tried running the code you have provided and have not encountered that issue. I am on windows using python 3.9, maybe it is a OS or version issue?

Comment: It may be a problem with the OS. The problem occurred on macOS and I haven't tried it on different operating systems.